# Hibernate - annotation validation

Tags: hibernate, validation, exception

in my spring mvc + hibernate web app i get following message on console 
when i try to validate my form

```
13:05:41.225 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor - Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
13:05:41.377 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils - Failed to meta-introspect annotation [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.validation.Valid.value()
13:05:41.631 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.notempty.NotEmptyValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.653 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
13:05:41.654 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.notempty.NotEmptyValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.671 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.size.SizeValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.702 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
13:05:41.703 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.size.SizeValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.704 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.notempty.NotEmptyValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.704 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.notempty.NotEmptyValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.705 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.size.SizeValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.705 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.size.SizeValidatorForCharSequence'
13:05:41.705 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotNullValidator'
13:05:41.719 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
13:05:41.720 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotNullValidator'
13:05:41.720 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.EmailValidator'
13:05:41.772 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
13:05:41.776 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.EmailValidator'
```

user form :

```
protected Long id;

protected String registrationNumber;

@NotNull
protected Civility civility;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 3)
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 3)
protected String lastName;

@Email
protected String email;
```

UserController

```
@PostMapping(path = "/submit/{id}", headers = "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest")
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse submit(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid SelfForm self, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
    .........
    }else{
    ...........
    }
    ..........
}
```

how should i act to get rid with this line in console

DEBUG org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils - Failed to meta-introspect annotation [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.validation.Valid.value()

Comment: do you have validation jar in your class path?

Comment: Yes of course : _compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.2.Final_

Comment: add this to your pom and chek: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->

Comment: I did, but it remains the same